How do I import a node library I have published to Azure Artifacts?
I am trying to import a test artifact into a test project.
I have created a simple node project, as follows, to try and isolate the problem I am having:
HelloWorld.tsx:
export const HelloWorld = () => {
    return "Hello World";
};

export default HelloWorld;

index.ts:
export { default as HelloWorld } from './HelloWorld';

package.json
{
  "name": "@test/helloworld",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "just a test",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^6.0.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.7",
    "@rollup/plugin-eslint": "^9.0.5",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.2.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.1.6",
    "rollup": "^4.14.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.3"
  }
}

.npmrc (for publishing to Azure)
registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MYCOMPANY/MYPROJECT/_packaging/publish-test/npm/registry/ 
always-auth=true

I have run npm publish, and have confirmed that the package is in my azure artifacts.
I created a new react-app, added the .npmrc file (so that the app can access my artifacts), and ran npm install @test/helloworld@1.0.0 which worked fine. I can confirm that the files are within the node_modules folder.
The issue I am getting is in the app trying to use this library:
import { HelloWorld } from '@test/helloworld' ; gives me the error: Cannot find module '@test/helloworld' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
I am certain that I am missing something exceptionally simple, as I am very new to typescript, and very very new to publishing node packages in general, let alone Azure. I am hoping someone can point to me where I have missed the simple step :)

We ended up dropping the use of Azure Artifacts, it was nothing but a nightmare for us. We're now using npmjs.org.

To publish an npm package in Azure Artifact and use it in a react app, you can refer to the steps below.
Create packages
I create the npm package following this blog TypeScript NPM Package Publishing: A Beginner’s Guide. (Refer to the steps before Testing your NPM package).
My index.ts:
function HelloWorld(): string {
  return "Hello World";
}

export = HelloWorld;

My package.json
{
  "name": "@test/helloworld",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "description": "This is a TS npm package",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "module": "./dist/index.mjs",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsup",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "***",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tsup": "^8.0.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.4"
  }
}

Publish packages
Connect your npm project to Azure Artifacts feeds follow this doc. Run npm publish to publish the package to the Azure Artifact.
Consume packages
I create my react app by running npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript.
Add .npmrc file to the root folder of my app.
Run npm install @test/helloworld@1.0.3 to install the package from Azure Artifact.
Import the package using import HelloWorld from '@test/helloworld';  and print 'Hello World' in App.
MyApp.tsx:
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import HelloWorld from '@test/helloworld';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          {HelloWorld()}
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

My app:

